# Equivalent condition for a exact sequence to split

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Consider the following split exact sequence of abelian groups $A,B,C$ characterized by the communicative diagram below with the isomorphism $\tau: B \rightarrow A \oplus C$:
[image: split exact sequence]

I’m trying to show that the existence of $\tau$ is equivalent to the existence of a homomorphism $f: B \rightarrow B$ s.t. $f^2=f$ and $\ker(f) = \text{im} (i)$. I was able to show „$\tau$ exists $\Rightarrow $ $f$ exists“, now I’m showing the other direction. I set:
$$
\tau(b):=(i^{-1}(b-f(b)),s(b))
$$
This is well defined because $b-f(b) \in \ker(f)=\text{im}(i)$ and invective because $s(b)=0 \Rightarrow b \in \ker(s)=\text{im(i)}=\ker(f) $ which means $0=b-f(b)=b$. I somehow have problems with subjectivity though. I try to find a $b$ s.t. $\tau(b)=(a,c)$ I tried: $b = i(a)+f(s^{-1}(c))$, because then $b-f(b)=i(a)+f(s^{-1}(c))-f[i(a)+f(s^{-1}(c))]=i(a)$ as desired but $s(b)=s(f(s^{-1}(c))) \neq c$, so I‘m stuck. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Since $s$ might not be injective, you can't assume $s^{-1}$ is a function.

Comment: You’re right $s^{-1}(x)$ always exists because of surjectivity but I didn’t check that $f(x)=f(y)$ for $x,y$ s.t. $s(x)=s(y)$. Which probably isn’t even the case, so I must’ve chosen $b$ wrong. Any idea what a better candidate would be?

Comment: $fs^{-1}(c)$ is still a singleton, so it does make some sense, despite the abuse of notation.

Comment: Ok yes if $f(x)\neq f(y)$ then $x-y$ isn’t in the $\ker f = \ker s$ which means $s(x) \neq s(y)$, so $fs^{-1}(c)$ is of course a unique element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ker(f)=\ker(s)$, the universal property of the quotient tells you that there is an injective homomorphism $h:C\to B$, such that $hs=f$. Since $hshs=hs$ and $h$ is injective we have $shs=s$ or $sf=s$, and $sfs^{-1}(c)=ss^{-1}(c)=c$

Answer (score 1):

Denoted $i^{-1}(id_{B}-f):B\to A$ by $t$, it is a retraction of $i$, i.e., $i\circ t=id_A$( this is actually the the splitting lemma ). Hence $B=ker\ t+im\ i.$ Since s is surjective, there exists some $b$ that $s(b)=c$ for each $c\in C$. Then we obtain that $b=(b-it(b))+it(b)=k+it(b)$, $s(b)=s(k)+s\circ it(b)=s(k).$
For each $c\in C$, we may find a $k$ in $ker\ t$ such that $s(k)=c.$